# Erro: Referência indefinida para 'sqlite3_open'

Tags: c, sqlite, compilação, sqlite3

Estou criando um software em C que utiliza o SQLite 3 como banco de dados, porem, ao compilar o projeto o Codeblocks me retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> createdata.c|| referência indefinida para 'sqlite3_open'|
>
> referência indefinida para 'sqlite3_errmsg'|

Como solucionar este erro?

Meu código:

```
int CriarBanco()
{
    sqlite3 *banco;
    char *MsgErro = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;

    /**Abrir banco de dados**/
    rc = sqlite3_open("produto.db", &banco);

    if(rc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nao foi possivel abrir o banco de dados.", sqlite3_errmsg(banco));
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "Banco aberto com sucesso.");

    return 0;
}
```

PS: Estou utilizando esta biblioteca `<sqlite3.h>` e estou compilando com o GCC.

Comment: Windows, Linux ou Mac? Como você instalou o SQLite neles?

Comment: Linux ubuntu já instalei sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisa mandar compilar o SQLite junto usando alguma variação desta linha de comando:

```
gcc main.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl
```

Comment: Executei o comando, porem retorno o seguinte erro:`gcc: error: sqlite3.c: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado`

Comment: Onde que fica guardado o arquivo *sqlite3.c*? Estou usando linux.

Comment: Se você não tem ele, tem que baixar https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: Procure por sqlite-amalgamation-3090100.zip em https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma olhada aqui Leonardo.