# SQLite3 com Dev-C++

Tags: sqlite3, dev-c++

Estou tentando fazer um teste de conexão com Dev-C++ e SQLite3 mas estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
```

Já adicionei:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

Já adicionei as dlls tudo como manda o figurino

O Código teste é o seguinte:

```
// definindo ponteiros SQLite3
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3 *handle;
int res;
char *filename;

filename = "caixaeletronico.db";

res = sqlite3_open(filename, &handle); // Aqui gera o erro
```

Se eu comentar a linha acima ele compila, ou seja ele encontra os includes normalmente, mas acho que não encontra a dll que está no diretório do Dev-C++ e no diretorio do executavel e do windows pra garantir.
Não creio que eu tenha que registras a dll do SQLite não é?

Comment: O problema esta na linkagem, não na compilação. Provavelmente você não adicionou a DLL para ser linkada ao seu programa. Ou adicionou o caminho errado, por exemplo.

Comment: Quando está compilando, está incluindo a biblioteca do SQLLite? Ou está compilando o fonte dele junto? Provavelmente é isto. Acho que é o mesmo problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94743/101 veja se é e eu respondo ou fecho como duplicata.

Comment: É a mesma questão sim bigown.